# I'm trying to find the security holes in this C code for a queue

Tags: c, security, malloc

I know that there's something fishy about the `malloc` part, but I'm having trouble seeing what's unsafe about this:

```
//que structure
typedef struct queue{
         int *que;  // the actual array of queue elements
         int head;   // the head index in que of the queue
         int count;  /// number of elements in queue
         int size; // max number of elements in queue
    } QUEUE;


void qManage(QUEUE **qptr, int flag, int size){
      if(flag){
              /* allocate a new queue */
              *qptr = malloc(sizeof(QUEUE));
              (*qptr)->head = (*qptr)->count = 0;
              (*qptr)->que = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
              (*qptr)->size = size;
    }
    else{
             /* delete the current queue */
             (void) free((*qptr)->que);
             (void) free(*qptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the assignment to find the security holes in the code, or implementing the queue?

Comment: To find the holes only. We have the code already

Comment: A flag named "flag" to determine if you're creating or deleting a queue?! Worry about the users of your API first; they'll do enough damage before they have a chance to worry about security.

Comment: I think that the answer may be 'what happens when you pass a negative value for size?', but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: I know it's unchecked , so the malloc doesn't take into account overriding something else. Or am I missing it?

Comment: Other then not checking if malloc() fails.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - Hmm, that would make sense , will look into it. thanks alot!

Comment: @Adel I added my comment as an answer, if that indeed is the problem, please remember to accept my answer.

Comment: How items are added will also be important.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII  - A quick google-search suggests to me that maybe malloc takes unsigned only, so you can't pass a neg. value?

Comment: What happens if someone passes in a QUEUE that is larger than the allowable malloc size?

Comment: @Adel malloc is implementation specifc. On my mac compiled with GCC, `malloc(-1)` returns NULL. The only other tying that I can think of is `what happens if malloc(sizeof(QUEUE)) returns NULL?` in that case, you would get a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when you try to dereference null to set `head`.

Comment: This exact piece of code is dissected here: http://nob.cs.ucdavis.edu/bishop/secprog/robust.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem this:
`What happens if you pass a negative value for 'size'?`

Another possible issue is that you do not check `*qptr` for `NULL` after you allocate, however, rarely would that be a problem in actual code, if it would ever happen, you have other errors to worry about.

Comment: It all depends on how much to allocate and where that value comes from. If it comes from a user-supplied input, an attacker could craft that input to cause a huge amount of memory to attempt to allocate, which would fail, exposing you to a variety of memory attacks as you write to that memory even if the allocation fails (so you can write to other in-use data).

Comment: @jeffsix correct.  I believe that that may be part of the issue there.